# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException thrown when running Azure function(V2) locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I created a queue trigger template of Azure function v2 in VS2017.
When I ran the project locally, the function runtime started successfully. But when I created a message in the queue, VS downloaded a JsonSerialization.cs file and pointed out the error. 
[image]

Details of default Exception settings:
[image]

It's a template generated by VS, so there seems no code issue like what I have found in other posts.

What I have tried:

- Publish the project to Azure, works.
- Run the project with function core tool(Cli) installed by npm, also works.

I guess the problem is related to the function Cli used by VS. But its runtime version is `2.0.11651.0`, same as the one installed by npm.

Have anyone met this before or got any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this exception caught by catch and then ignored? Could you add call stack?

Comment: @Mikhail You find the key! I can ignore the exception when it's thrown and everything works fine. But it has no catch and can't be ignored by default on my side. I have to do exception settings with a simple tick. Thanks a lot, you can post it as an answer or I will do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This exception is internal and should be caught by the runtime. Feel free to ignore it in exception settings, and then everything should just work.