# Debugging Azure Function - VoidMethodInvoker.cs not found

Tags: azure, azure-functions

[image]

I keep getting this message whenever I try to debug an azure function in VS2017 and I can't figure out why.

Any input or assistance appreciated.

It appears to be looking for some kind of azure web jobs library:

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error message in your function Cli output?

Comment: No errors are visible.

Comment: My understanding here is that JobHost.cs is part of the azure web jobs SDK. My function project has the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus Nuget package referenced (3.0.0-beta5) as the trigger on the function is "ServiceBusTrigger". I'm still unsure why the debugger is looking for that file in that specific directory, however.

Comment: Yes, it is. When do you get this message? After you debug(F5) your function, or after you trigger your function by sending message to service bus? Have you tried to continue to run your code when you got the exception?

Comment: After you hit F5 or F10... it doesn't seem to stop the function running and deserializing the message to an object but it's a bit of a pain.

Comment: Did you get `Exceprion User-Unhandled` prompt? Might be an internal error as it doesn't stop your function from working.

Comment: "Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll" is the only error I can see.

Comment: Just in case you are still stuck. Now VS2017 has released update to 15.8.1, including some update for Azure Functions and Web Job Tools, I recommend you to have a try. If you find any way to get rid of this, you could file an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This `'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll` should be a first chance exception when function is triggered, no need to worry as it has been handled by function host.

If you don't see any red error info in function cli window (pop out when debugging) and your code is successfully executed, this should be an internal error.

Can't reproduce it on my side, hence just offer some suggestions based on my understanding.

Delete function sdk folder `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions` and install latest `1.0.14` package in your function project.

If it doesn't work, I recommend you to download [VoidMethodInvoker.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/VoidMethodInvoker.cs) or [JobHost.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHost.cs) to detect the exception. Then ignore it by configuring Exception settings. Met [an internal exception on queue trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831559/newtonsoft-json-jsonreaderexception-thrown-when-running-azure-functionv2-local) before.

Comment: Thanks installing the microsoft.net.sdk.function latest package fixed my issue (upgraded from 3.1.1 to 4.1.3).